# Combine neighbors lists while estimating a spatial lag model with multiple time periods with R

Tags: r, spdep

I am trying to estimate a spatial lag model for a dataset of U.S. school districts with four years of data. The issue is that the dimensions of the school districts change every year (i.e. the boundaries shift for some of them), so I need to create a neighbors list for each year individually.

Is it possible to combine the neighbors lists I created for each year into one so that I can estimate a regression across all four years of data? I am working with the spdep and spatialreg packages in R. I have already estimated four separate ones for each year, but I am wondering if it is possible to pool all the years together and estimate a regression for all four as one would were spatial autocorrelation not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `union.nb` function from `spdep`. As long as you've created your neighbourhood objects from the same set of points or polygons then you can combine them this way.

For example:

Generate 20 random points:

```
> set.seed(123)
> xy = cbind(runif(20), runif(20))
```

Compute adjacent if distance is 0 to 0.2 and another if distance is 0.1 to 0.3. Note these ranges overlap:

```
> d1 = dnearneigh(xy, 0, .2)
> d2 = dnearneigh(xy, 0.1, .3)
```

That gives us two `nb` objects:

```
> d1
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 20 
Number of nonzero links: 26 
Percentage nonzero weights: 6.5 
Average number of links: 1.3 
5 regions with no links:
6 15 18 19 20
> d2
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 20 
Number of nonzero links: 60 
Percentage nonzero weights: 15 
Average number of links: 3 
2 regions with no links:
4 11
```

We can plot them to see what they look like, and add their `union.nb`:

```
> par(mfrow=c(2,2))
> plot(d1, coords=xy)
> plot(d2, coords=xy)
> plot(union.nb(d1, d2), coords=xy)
```

[image]

Top row is `d1` and `d2`, bottom is the union.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is getting towards what I need, but I just edited my original question for better clarity.